# IDE Tool to convert XML into a Java class nonprogramatically

Tags: java, json, xml

How do I convert an XML document to a java class non-programatically?

In visual studio, I can simply use Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Class and that will generate a C# class from pasted XML document.

Is there such tool in eclipse, STS or some other java IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found online tool to do so at https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-java-converter.

Comment: One more online tool https://javadev.github.io/xml-to-json/